# How do i get channels into my ShippingMethod-Step

Tags: symfony, sylius

I have multiple channels in my shop.
The channels all have exactly the same product.
Now i want to allow the user to choose between the different channels
in the checkout-process.

Optimally the shipping methods are grouped by channel.
e.g.

```
===========================
| Channel 1
===========================
| ( ) Pickup
| (x) Shipping
|                => Move on

===========================
| Channel 2
===========================
| ( ) Pickup
| (x) Shipping
|                => Move on
```

It i now select one of the options multiple things happen:

1. The channel is switched
2. The ShippingMethod is selectd
3. The Cart is transferred to the other channel

All these should be possible with sylius.
My biggest problem is kind of basic.

Sylius uses the ResourceBundle to load Entities from the repositories.
I have a route configured like that:

```
sylius_shop_checkout_select_shipping:
path: /select-shipping
methods: [GET, PUT]
defaults:
    _controller: sylius.controller.order:updateAction
    _sylius:
        event: select_shipping
        flash: false
        template: SyliusShopBundle:Checkout:selectShipping.html.twig
        form: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\Checkout\SelectShippingType
        repository:
            method: find
            arguments:
                - "expr:service('sylius.context.cart').getCart()"
        state_machine:
            graph: sylius_order_checkout
            transition: select_shipping
        redirect:
            route: sylius_shop_checkout_select_payment
            parameters: []
```

There is ohne a single "repository" key allowed.
Do i have to build my own controller and use the repositiories directly from the service-container?